Recreating a bike seatpost in Fusion 360
I have to recreate the seatpost for a 3d printed water bottle holder but I can't seem to figure out how I should make it, this is the drawing from the manufacturer of the bike so this must be what they use to make it, everything is confusing. I'm not even sure if it's the top part or the one lower, the parts with yellow numbers is what I need

We probably need more details...

I'm very good in reading technical drawings, but, I struggle reading this drawing. Where is this located on the bike? Please provide an overall overview and explain what we are looking at. I'm not sure this is a 3D printing question, it could probably be better hosted at SE.Engineering.
